Is there a way to enable energy saving mode for secondary monitors that are not being used in a multiple monitor setup?
I am using Windows (specifically, Windows 10) and I have multiple monitors. The thing is, sometimes I am just using one of them, but the others remain turned on even if I am not working (or reading) at the content of that monitor's "area".
My screen saving configuration is adjusted for 5 minutes of inactivity, so, after that time, all monitors will enter energy saving mode.
What I have in mind is: Is there any built-in configuration or third party software that tracks the "area" that is being used, and, if there is no activity in the areas of the other monitors, the software would allow the other monitors to enter energy saving mode after the time set?
I imagine the software would need to track only mouse activity, not the keyboard's, to consider if the PC is in activity or not. This way, all I would need to do to wake a monitor would be to hover my mouse over it's area.
Plus: is this also achievable in Linux (specifically, Ubuntu)?
In both OSes, I just found global settings that apply for all monitors at the same time, I didn't find anything related to controlling monitors in a different manner.

Why not just use the Windows + P hotkey to cycle to whichever monitor you are actually using at the time, that would turn off the other monitor.

because that command only cycles through multiple monitor modes. i want them extended as they already are. i use the secondary monitors quite frequently when i need to read or to look at tables with lots of data, while i code in the other screen. but sometimes i simply forget to shut them down on long periods of not using...
